# Запись в файл после определённой строки

Tags: c++

Как после определенной строки в файле внести изменения?

Answer (score 2):

Размер «записи» в текстовом файле нефиксирован, и сложные структуры наподобие таблицы строк не предусмотрены. Это значит, что вы не можете просто найти номер байта, с которого начинается данная строка.

Текстовый формат по существу является потоковым форматом. Вы не сможете обработать строку `N`, не пройдя предыдущие строки.

Самое простое, что вы можете сделать — это читать строки по одной и записывать их в новый выходной файл.

Например, на C++:

```
{
    std::ifstream infile(inpath);
    std::ofstream outfile(outpath);

    std::string line;
    for (int lineno = 0; std::getline(infile, line); lineno++)
    {
        if (lineno > N)
            line = change(line);
        outfile << line << std::endl;
    }
} // закрыть файлы
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Открыть файл для чтения и записи
2. Найти нужное место после которого вносятся изменения
3. Переставить указатель записи на него функцией seekp()
4. Внести изменения функцией write()

Но обычно проще считать весь файл, поменять что нужно и перезаписать

Comment: А какая именно магия происходит в пункте 2? Как узнать «нужное место»?

Comment: В момент первой записи в файл. Запомнить место, забить туда какую-нибудь ерунду НУЖНОГО РАЗМЕРА. А потом вернуться и вставить необходимое. Я так делал.

Comment: Про "магию" понятия не имею, я в глаза не видел что там у ТСа в текстовых файлах и что он собрался туда вставлять :) Я бы сделал еще один файл, в котором бы запомниал смещения начала строк, при создании текстового файла. Но в целом затея дописать что-то в середину текстового файла не очень удачная.